# Wrong values in Interim Accounts when returning stock

Tags: odoo-12, accounting

I am using anglo saxon accounting ​method in my accounting and I use average pricing as my costing method in inventory. But I am struggling with the vendor stock returning process because after validating the return, stock interim account values are not as I expected. I want to return the stock to the vendor to the price of what bought but it returned to the current price.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/12.0/accounting/others/inventory/avg_price_valuation.html

As the above link says, Odoo can cater stock returns to their purchase price (see section: “Further thoughts on anglo saxon mode”). But I run the same test case on my server (Odoo 12) as well as the Odoo demo server, but it returns to the current price.

Is there any specific configuration for enabling this process or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is inherit `view_company_form` view and add `anglo_saxon_accounting` field

```
<record id="view_company_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.company.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.company</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='rml_header1']" position="after">
            <separator string=""/>
            <group >
               <field name="anglo_saxon_accounting" />
            </group>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Hi @user3676872, I have already enable anglo saxon accounting. But It does not return stock to its purchase price. When returning, it calculates FIFO and generates the new cost for the product. But I want to return the products to its purchase price. Not for the newly calculated FIFO price.

Comment: so you need to do some custmoization on `_prepare_account_move_line` by adding  `debit_value = self.origin_returned_move_id.price_unit * qty`